# LD_PRELOAD stack and data segments memory allocation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Hello,

I'm writing a Linux module (based on a GitHub project called "Ccontrol") to create cache partitioning (a.k.a page coloring) for mitigating timing- side-channel attacks (for preventing attacks like Prime+Probe).

I've used `LD_PRELOAD` system env variable to overwrite all the `malloc()`,`calloc()` and `free()` calls and replace them with color aware calls.

Now I'm looking for away to color the stack and the data segments also.

What is the system-call/Library for allocating memory for a new born process?

Is there a way to overwrite this call(without recompiling the kernel) using `LD_PRELOAD` or any other method?

Thank you all in advance,

Gal

Answer (score 1):

There are two memory allocating syscalls: `sbrk`, which expands the (continuous) heap segment and `mmap`, which is used to map separate anonymous memory segments into the address space of the calling process.

You won't be able to use `LD_PRELOAD` to override these everywhere, though.
You'll only be able to do it if the code you're overriding makes these calls through the DSO-exported libc wrappers, which means you won't be able to override direct syscalls and syscalls make through unexported wrappers (DSO-internal (`__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`), which most libc implementations use quite a bit. You also won't be able to override the syscalls made by the dynamic linker.

If you need a robust way of overriding the calls, you'll need to turn to `ptrace` or modify the kernel.